# What is the functionality difference between the Reference of a class and its object/instance in python while calling its objects?

Tags: python, oop

I was searching for the meaning of default parameters `object`,`self` that are present as default class and function parameters, so moving away from it, if we are calling an attribute of a class should we use `Foo` (class reference) or should we use `Foo()` (instance of the class).

Comment: if `foo = Foo()`, then `foo.bar(x) == Foo.bar(foo, x)`

Comment: But why if 'foo = Foo', then Foo.bar(x) is an error.

Comment: because then `bar` is an unbound method.  That is simply how classes work in python - methods get "bound" and then implicitly receive the instance as the first argument when called on an instance.

Comment: Would making attribute 'static' bypass the use of instance. Also by receiving the instance do you mean that code 'Foo().bar' would return a method object which would be the first parameter to it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are *reading* a normal attribute then it doesn't matter. If you are *binding* a normal attribute then you must use the correct one in order for the code to work. If you are accessing a *descriptor* then you must use an instance.

Comment: By normal attribute do you mean attributes which are not static? What difference does binding a value to the attribute make? How does both reference and instance differ in their generation and operation?

Comment: I mean attributes that are not descriptors.

Answer (score 0):

The details of python's class semantics are quite well documented in the [data model](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html). Especially the `__get__` semantics are at work here. Instances basically stack their namespace on top of their class' namespace and add some boilerplate for calling methods.

---

There are some large "it depends on what you are doing" gotchas at work here. The most important question: do you want to access *class* or *instance* attributes? Second, do you want *attribute* or *methods*?

Let's take this example:

```
class Foo(object):
  bar = 1
  baz = 2
  def __init__(self, foobar="barfoo", baz=3):
    self.foobar = foobar
    self.baz = baz

  def meth(self, param):
    print self, param

  @classmethod
  def clsmeth(cls, param):
    print cls, param

  @staticmethod
  def stcmeth(param):
    print param
```

Here, `bar` is a *class* attribute, so you can get it via `Foo.bar`. Since instances have implicit access to their class namespace, you can also get it as `Foo().bar`. `foobar` is an instance attribute, since it is never bound to the class (only instances, i.e. `self`s) - you can only get it as `Foo().foobar`. Last, `baz` is *both* a class and an instance attribute. By default, `Foo.baz == 2` and `Foo().baz == 3`, since the class attribute is hidden by the instance attribute set in `__init__`.

Similarly, in an assignment there are slight differences whether you work on the class or an instance. `Foo.bar=2` will set the class attribute (also for all instances) while `Foo().bar=2` will *create* an instance attribute that shadows the class attribute for this specific instance.

For methods, it is somewhat similar. However, here you get the implicit `self` parameter for instance method (what a function is if defined for a class). Basically, the call `Foo().meth(param=x)` is silently translated to `Foo.meth(self=Foo(), param=x)`. This is why it is usually not valid to call `Foo.meth(param=x)` - meth is not "bound" to an instance and thus lacks the `self` parameter.

Now, sometimes you do not need any instance data in a method - for example, you have strict string transformation that is an implementation detail of a larger parser class. This is where `@classmethod` and `@staticmethod` come into play. A classmethod's first parameter is always the class, as opposed to the instance for regular methods. `Foo().clsmeth(param=x)` *and* `Foo.clsmeth(param=x)` result in a call of `clsmethod(cls=Foo, param=x)`. Here, the two are equivalent. Going one step further, a staticmethod doesn't get any class or instance information - it is like a raw function bound to the classes namespace.